# How can I save my Emacs settings?

Tags: emacs, dot-emacs

I am using the Emacs editor, and every time I start Emacs, I lose my previous settings.

For example, every time I have to type:

- <kbd>M-x</kbd> `cua-mode` <kbd>RET</kbd>
- <kbd>M-x</kbd> `auto-complete-mode` <kbd>RET</kbd>

How can I save my settings in Emacs?

Thanks.

Comment: I googled the subject and top 5 results resolve this.  Can you explain why you couldn't google this yourself?  I'm actually curious and not just trying to be snarky.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best answer I can think of is to point you at the manual:
http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Customization.html

In particular, see the sections on "Easy Customization" and the "Init File"; but I would recommend at least skimming over everything in this section.

Answer (score 5):

You can add them to your .emacs file.

```
(cua-mode)
(auto-complete-mode)
```

If you find that there are already things in your .emacs file, then you might want to add the commands at the end.

Comment: In general you want to be explicit about whether you are turning a mode on or off, as most modes *toggle* their state when no argument is supplied. So you probably want to use `(cua-mode 1)` and `(auto-complete-mode 1)` (although the latter is not a default part of Emacs, so I haven't verified that one).

Comment: Would `t` work as well?  e.g. I have `(setq inhibit-splash-screen t)` in my .emacs file. I guess I'm asking if t and 1 are equivalent.

Comment: No, `t` and `1` are not equivalent. That is not to say that they won't sometimes have the same effect, but it's certainly not a guarantee. `t` means True (with `nil` meaning False), but you should check the documentation to be certain of the valid values for a given variable or function argument. For your example, `C-h v inhibit-splash-screen RET` tells us that *any* non-`nil` value will prevent the splash screen from showing. For the mode functions, a value of `0` usually disables the mode (`nil` would toggle), so even if `t` also enables, it seems more consistent to also use a number.

Comment: I see that in Emacs 24, the `define-minor-mode` macro now makes calling a minor mode function without an argument from lisp (i.e. non-interactively) equivalent to `(mode-function 1)`. Perhaps to avoid this very issue.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think I should have read the user manual.

Answer (score 0):

In your emacs directory there is a site-lisp folder. Normally it will be empty. you could create a file default.el in this folder. Add these two lines
(cua-mode t)
(auto-complete-mode)
and save it.This will be executed during Init. If you want to set environment variables for your emacs application only(not permanent) add a file called site-start.el in the site-lisp directory and define value for that variable ex:(setenv "VARIABLENAME" "value"). The site-lisp directory is in the standard search path for Lisp library.

Comment: `default.el` is not the way to save user-specific settings. If you place it in the site-lisp directory then it will affect *all* users on the machine (this being its purpose). If you put it a directory which is added to your path by your own user init file, then there's no point -- you could have just used your init file. See the details in the manual under "Init File", as linked in the accepted answer.